# SQL Server Data Tools

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to write a aeb application in Visual Studio by using ASP.NET and SQL Server, but when I am trying to add a database file in my application to create a database then after "App_Data permission notification", this notification is appearing on my screen. I have installed the database twice, but it doesn't solve my problem - any solution?

I have installed SQL Server 2022 Express database and SQL Server Management Studio, both I have not seen any local database remote option. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: I hope you're not referring to the `App_Data` folder disaster from ASP.NET 2.0 back in 2005?

Comment: SQL Server isn't a file-based database. You're trying to use User Instance databases, an obsolete feature of SQL Server Express which hosters stopped supporting 10-15 years ago. Having to install 100 SQL Server Express instances to handle customers instead of eg 2 big SQL Server Standard instances was so expensive they'd have to charge *more*. If you have SQL Server Express installed there's no reason to use `App_Data` in the first place